# How to access data which is stored in server via UI?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. In that application I have to access the data from the server into my cell using User Interface. I dont know much about How to save data in server and How to access in my cell.

If any body knows then help me. or give me some links to study about that.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: -1 you need to ask a much narrower question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) tutorial helps you to do that. Basically you need know about few things. You need to store the data in database  first may be mysq and so on. Using server side languages like php, java and many you can get those data in the form of JSON which is very handy. Later on you can parse them and display it in your UI. You will get to know about that in the above mentioned tutorial. You have video there as well. All the best

Comment: Thnks vini ... I ll check it and revert u back...

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to communicate with the Server (Get data from Server or Upload data to server). I would suggest you to get some idea about [Web-Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) it will help you a lot.

Below I am giving you a method which I am using.

for this you need a request URL by using this you will get the response from server, so later you can read the response result and can use wherever you want.

```
public String getResult(String url) {

        Log.v(TAG, "Final Requsting URL is : :"+url);

        String line = "";
        String responseData = null;

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String x = "";
            URL httpurl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection  tc= httpurl.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new   
                                 InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                x = sb.toString();
            }
            responseData = new String(x);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException uh){            
            Log.v("NewWebHelper", "Unknown host :");
            uh.printStackTrace();
        }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           Log.v("NewWebHelper", "FileNotFoundException :");
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("NewWebHelper", "IOException :");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.v("NewWebHelper", "Exception :");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseData;
    }
```

---

Let me know if you get any trouble with this code, shortly I'll try to share How to upload data to server example code too